# Ruby on Rails Sign up error if @user.save

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I'm trying to create a simple app to learn ruby, and while creating the sign up form an error appears:

> NoMethodError in UsersController#create
>   undefined method `limit' for nil:NilClass

```
 def create
@user = User.new(user_params)
if @user.save
  flash.now[:noticia] = "#{user.nombre} se ha registrado correctamente"
  redirect_to root_path
else
```

It says that the error stays at if @user.save

The whole code is:

```
def sign_up
@user = User.new
end

def create
@user = User.new(user_params)
if @user.save
  flash.now[:noticia] = "#{user.nombre} se ha registrado correctamente"
  redirect_to root_path
else
  render 'sign_up'
end
end

def user_params
params.require(:user).permit(:nombre, :email, :password, :confirm_password)
end
end
```

Which is the problem?

Thank you!

Comment: Can you post the log of the error? The server console will show it, if it's running in development mode.

Comment: Are there any validations or callbacks in your `User` model?

Comment: @Sergiossss, can you post the code in your `user` model?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error says `undefined method for nil:NilClass` so the user query is not finding a user. Run the `User.new` query in the console which should help you understand why that query is not working. Have you set up the `user_params` correctly to reflect the user attribute names? For example should `confirm_password` be `password_confirmation`?